# Infinite Groups in SageMath(or in GAP)

Tags: group-theory, gap, sagemath

I am once again asking more software-related questions, but I am happy to learn a general answer as well. I'm curious about how the is_infinite function works in SageMath (or in GAP). Does it simply check whether we input something that is already known to be infinite or not? Or does it print "infinite" after a specific number of elements? Or does it actually check if the group is infinite? I assume it's not a numerical answer to check if the group is infinite or not since the program can't count until infinity. So, I'm wondering what the method is for checking if a group is infinite or not (in SageMath and in general).
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106606/what-is-an-algorithm-for-determining-if-a-finitely-presented-group-is-finite?noredirect=1&lq=1). I suppose that the Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration procedure is used, to show that the group is finite (given a presentation). There are many posts saying that the size function did not work for an infinite group, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503067/computing-whether-a-particular-finitely-presented-group-is-infinite-with-gap?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The Todd-Coxeter procedure can only prove that a group (or more generally the index of a given subgroup) is finite. It cannot prove that a group is infinite - it runs forever when given an infinite group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, this is what I meant by saying "that the group is finite".

Comment: There are a few easy tests for infiniteness, which would be carried out by GAP of SageMath, such as does the group have infinite abelianization. If the tests fail, and quick attempts to prove finiteness also fail, then these functions return no answer. They should never return a wrong answer. If they do then there is a bug in the code!

Comment: Thank you both! I am now reading your references, it would be great if someone could write a comprehensive summary of these things and write an answer. I could do that too but it is a bit weird to answer the question that I asked..

Comment: It depends what kind of group you have. Methods for finitely presented groups differ from those for matrix groups in characteristic zero, e.g., and there are methods that are not guaranteed to succeed. I suggest you focus your question more on a particular class of groups you are interested in.

Comment: I would add to the comment of @ahulpke that, unlike the situation for finitely presented groups, where finiteness is undecidable in general, the finiteness of a matrix group in characteristic zero is decidable by an algorithm of Detinko, Flannery and O'Brien, at least over fields that allow exact computation, such as number fields and function fields.